# Message listener only begins firing after browserAction has been clicked

Tags: google-chrome-extension

It appears that a message from *content* to *background* only begins firing **after** backgroundAction has been run at least once.

In the below code example, a click on browserAction turns the page red, and a click on the page body turns the page blue (via a message sent by the content script).

If I click the page body first, nothing happens. It only begins working **after** I've clicked browserAction once.

Why is this happening and how can I make it so the message listener fires without having browserAction run first?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**content.js**

```js
$(function(){
  $('body').on('click', function() {
    // Send a message to background.js
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(true, function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });
  });
});
```

**background.js**

```js
// Make background red when browserAction is cliked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
  });
});

// Make background blue when any message is received
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue"'
  });
  return true;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always in such cases use [the debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging). The error I'm seeing here in the extension's background page console which can be opened on chrome://extensions page:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "...". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

When `runtime.onMessage` is executed after a message from the content script Chrome doesn't know that `executeScript` was initiated by a user action so the code is blocked.

As for `browserAction.onClicked`, it is always invoked on user's interaction so `"permissions": ["activeTab"]` is sufficient for the code executed in the eventjob context of the issued click. And it creates temporary permission to modify the active tab, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab):

> The following user gestures enable activeTab:
>
> - Executing a browser action
> - Executing a page action
> - Executing a context menu item
> - Executing a keyboard shortcut from the commands API
> - Accepting a suggestion from the omnibox API

- **Solution #1** (the best) would be to avoid injecting any code from the background script and do everything in the content script based on messages from the background script.
- **Solution #2** would be to add the required permission to manifest.json:

  ```
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "<all_urls>"]
  ```

Comment: The _<all_urls>_ permission did it. It's still unclear why without that permission it still works, though only after browserAction fires.

Comment: wOxxOm, you explained why `browserAction.onClicked` works without _<all_urls>_ permissions, but did not explain why `runtime.onMessage` successfully fires **after** browserAction, even though it does not have permissions.

Comment: @miniml, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab "Invoking activeTab" section.